# Getting codeship deployments to digital ocean working

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, codeship

Oh god why is this so hard. I've now spent 3 days trying to get this seemingly simple crap to work.

I need it to:
- npm install on CI server (works)
- run tests (works)
- build angular frontend (works)
- ship code to server via rsync (works)
- ssh into server (works) 
- - and npm install (doesn't work. dies because of npm warnings, I think)
- - restart pm2 process (doesn't work as there's no elegant way to say start or restart)

At the deploy step, I have this script in the codeship UI

```
rsync -avz --exclude 'node_modules' ~/clone/
root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/root/my-project/
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx cd /root/my-project && bash ./postDeploy.sh
```

Then the `postDeploy.sh` script is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
npm install --silent &> /dev/null
/usr/local/bin/pm2 stop --silent keystone &> /dev/null
/usr/local/bin/pm2 start keystone.js 2> /dev/null
```

I'm trying to swallow errors with this trick. `&> /dev/null`

There are a few vulnerabilities in the project that are unfortunately deep inside a core module and not fixable by me so I need npm to just be quiet in this case.

Then there's the PM2 thing which is slightly annoying. I need to issue a stop command, but if the service is not running it will fail, so again I need to swallow errors. The start command is probably fine.

I think maybe what's happening now is that because I swallow all output codeship's script runner assumes it fails?

I have tried to use the half-baked debug tool, but it magically asks me for a password when I try to login in... Eh?

Also @codeship it would be amazing if 80% of the helpful articles that google has indexed didn't lead to dead pages on your site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to use the half-baked debug tool, but it magically asks me for a password when I try to login in... Eh?

I'd say this was a correct instinct. There are too many possible scenarios for why you're coming across these unintended behaviors and nothing short of running the build live with a ssh debug session will likely get to the bottom of that.

Please see our documentation section for [troubleshooting password prompts for ssh debug sessions](https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/builds-and-configuration/ssh-access/#prompted-for-password).

If an ssh debug session doesn't solve your situation, then please reach out to us at support@codeship.com with your build url and we'll take a closer look.